# makefile woes , attempting to compile libdai

Tags: make

I'd like to compile libDAI. This comes with a Makefile.conf having the line

```
MEXFLAGS:=CXX\#g++ CXXFLAGS\#'$(CCFLAGS)'
```

which seems to cause trouble when i try using 'make'

```
jeremy@jrr:~/jeremy.rutman@gmail.com/techdev/Research/clothes_specific

/fashionista/fashionista_v0.2/lib/libdai$ make 

/usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/mex -Iinclude CXX#g++
CXXFLAGS#'-Wno-deprecated -Wall -W -Wextra -fpic'  -DDAI_WITH_BP
-DDAI_WITH_FBP -DDAI_WITH_TRWBP -DDAI_WITH_MF -DDAI_WITH_HAK -DDAI_WITH_LC -DDAI_WITH_TREEEP -DDAI_WITH_JTREE -DDAI_WITH_MR -DDAI_WITH_GIBBS -DDAI_WITH_CBP -DDAI_WITH_DECMAP -Llib -ldai -lgmpxx -lgmp -output +libdai/dai.mexa64 src/matlab/dai.cpp src/matlab/matlab.cpp lib/libdai.a
/home/jeremy/jeremy.rutman@gmail.com/techdev/Research/clothes_specific/fashionista/fashionista_v0.2/lib/libdai/CXX#g++
not found; check that you are in the correct current folder, and check
the spelling of
'/home/jeremy/jeremy.rutman@gmail.com/TrendiGuru/techdev/Research/clothes_specific/fashionista/fashionista_v0.2/lib/libdai/CXX#g++'.
make: *** [+libdai/dai.mexa64] Error 255
```

it seems like CXX is some variable that didnt get set. I tried taking it out and leaving MEXFLAGS:=g++ but the same thing happens more or less.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to the following line

```
MEXFLAGS:=CXX=#$(CC) CXXFLAGS\#'$(CCFLAGS)'
```

Make sure that CC is defined somewhere before :

```
CC=g++
```